# how to add an empty array to a json payload?

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

**Is it possible to add an array to a json payload?**

For example, let's say this is my payload:

```
        string json = @"{
          'channel': {
            'title': 'Star Wars',
            'link': 'http://www.starwars.com',
            'description': 'Star Wars blog.',
            'obsolete': [{'something':'awesome'},{'a':'b'}],
            'item': [],
            'nested':[{'upgrademe':'please'}, {'upgrademe':'no'}]
          }
        }";
```

The result I'd like would be something like this:

```
        string json = @"{
          'channel': {
            'title': 'Star Wars',
            'link': 'http://www.starwars.com',
            'description': 'Star Wars blog.',
            'obsolete': [{'something':'awesome'},{'a':'b'}],
            'item': [],
            'nested':[{'upgrademe':'please', 'emptyArray':[]}, {'upgrademe':'no'}]
          }
        }";
```

For every `channel.nested` where `upgrademe` == `please` then I'd like to add an empty array like `[]`.

before:

`'nested':[{'upgrademe':'please'}, {'upgrademe':'no'}]`

after:

`'nested':[{'upgrademe':'please', 'emptyArray':[]}, {'upgrademe':'no'}]`

My current implementation:

```
    public static JObject AddArray(this JObject jObject, string path, string key, string value)
    {
        var obs = jObject.SelectToken(path);
        if (obs == null)
        {
            return jObject;
        }

        foreach (var jsonObject in obs)
        {
            if (jsonObject.SelectToken(key).ToString().ToLower() != value.ToLower())
            {
                continue;
            }

            jObject.SelectToken(path).Parent.AddAfterSelf(new JValue(new JProperty("emptyArray", new JArray())));
        }

        return jObject;
    }
```

I'm getting an exception on this line:

[image]

usage example:

```
        var result = jobject.AddArray("channel.nested", "upgrademe", "please");
```

the above says the following:

> find the object "channel.nested" and when upgrademe==please, add a sibbling node as an empty array

**How do we conditionally add an array object to a json payload?**

Comment: not understanding the relevance of your comment @AlexM

Comment: Try it without JValue e.g. `AddAfterSelf(new JProperty("emptyArray", new JArray()))`

Comment: @AmanB that was it! please make it into an answer

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're adding a new property into an object. You don't need to use `JValue`

Just use `JProperty` directly:

`AddAfterSelf(new JProperty("emptyArray", new JArray()))`